# Mozilla Firefox password manager change path of key3.dp file on hard disk

Tags: security, firefox

In the moment I use a strong master Password to protect the saved passwords in the file logins.json. According to [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1084997) even if you do not use a master password the file logins.json is encrypted by using an encryption key that is stored in the key3.db file.

Is it possible to let Firefox know that the key3.db file is located on another hard disk folder like X:\CrpytedVault\FF-Passwords instead the default profile folder.

Say my Notebook gets stolen and we assume that the CrpytedVault that contains the `key3.db` file cannot be cracked.

Then the logins.json is worthless for the attacker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Key3.db) `key3.db` is part of the profile folder, so it doesn't seem like it can be moved on its own. Some options that come to mind:

- Move the entire profile folder. Firefox supports [arbitrary locations for the profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Changing_Profile_Folder_Location#Modify_profiles.ini_to_point_to_the_new_location_-_Advanced). Pro: this is more secure than just encrypting the passwords (since the profile contains other sensitive information like cookies, history, cache, etc). Con: the profile can be rather big.
- Use a symbolic link to move `key3.db` to a different disk but pretend to Firefox that it's still in the profile directory (yes, NTFS supports [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)). Pro: it's what you want (move the file to an encrypted disk/folder). Con: it might not be all that useful if you're thinking about a malware that copies your profile folder while it's "active" (while your encrypted storage is decrypted).

Comment: Hi moving the profile folder sounds good, I did not have that idea. 
I also think it adds an extra level of security:
1. If my notebook gets stolen the thief needs to crack my VeraCrypt Vault to even try to mess with the profile folder.
2. A stupid maleware maybe just scans the default location for the profile folders, since it is rather unusual that this location changes